# Switch from Google Universal Analytics to GA4

Tags: google-analytics-4

As per google we need to use this snippet to migrate to GA4 from UA.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX-Y"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');         // Universal Analytics property.
  gtag('config', 'TAG_ID');  // Google Analytics 4 property.
</script>
```

I have used this script and it works fine till now.

My question is, will having UA-XXXXX tag in above (src) url still keep GA4 working after 1st July when UA expires?
I want my GA4 Tag to continue to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Will having the `UA-XXXXX` tag in the above (src) url keep GA4 working after 1st July when UA expires?**

Yes, It will work and will not impact your GA4.

---

Will UA collect the data after July 1st, 2023?

- UA free will stop processing the data after July 1, 2023
- GA Premium (360) will stop processing the data after July 1, 2024

---

Bit more detail on this

The `id=UA-XXXXX-Y` part in `googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX-Y` is an optional param.

The main `gtag` js library is `googletagmanager.com/gtag/js` and it is global for all Google Products.

Comment: Any source to prove your point?
Because the id in src=https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX-Y is of UA-XXX and UA stops on 1st July, hence I was wondering if this will impact my ga4 or not.

Comment: Just confirming, I won't need to replace that expired id=UA-XXXX with gtag id=G-XXX before 1st July in the src=googletagmanager.com/gtag/js ?

Comment: The `UA-XXXXX-Y` part in `googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX-Y` is an optional param.  The main gtag js library is `googletagmanager.com/gtag/js` and it is global for all Google Products

Comment: Thats right, you just need to make sure this line always stays.`gtag('config', 'TAG_ID');  // Google Analytics 4 property.`