# How can I send data to multiple data streams from one web page using GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I would like to send data to multiple GA4 data streams from one web page. I simply want the data to go to two properties instead of just one. It would be nice if it was as simple as something like this:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');
  gtag('config', 'G-YYYYYYYYYY');
</script>
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do? If so, how should I do it?

I cannot seem to find information on how this is done specifically with GA4 and I don't want to experiment and risk making an error that causes problems in data collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your setup, When you trigger an event, ***it will be sent to both of the  GA4 id's automatically as you have configured both of them.***

The real challenge will come when you only want to send an event to only one id.

---

**How can you send an event only to one GA4 property?**

You can use this by using `send_to` parameter in your code, which includes the target id `G-XXXXXXX` `or G-YYYYYYY`  for eg:

```
gtag('event','conversion', { 'send_to': '<TARGET_ID>' });
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify, I can use the code exactly as I had it in my question? (swapping in the actual IDs of course)

Comment: Yes :) Please accept/upvote the answer if found useful.

Comment: What do you make of the fact that an ID (the ID of the data stream?) is sent as an argument in the URL, but not two IDs? This is one thing that made me unsure. If it's important to include the ID as an argument in the URL, why wouldn't we need to send both IDs?

Comment: By url you mean this? https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX

Comment: That's right. It has one of the IDs in it but not both.

Comment: That id is just to preconfigure some basic configs, however, it is not mandatory.  The main js file is `gtag/js` I have answered the exact question you have on the URL and id here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76529343/switch-from-google-universal-analytics-to-ga4/76531274#76531274